# How to reverse the open up animation of content view on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

```js
function moveRectangles(event) {
  var rectangles = document.querySelectorAll('.rectangle');
  var gap = 5; // Gap between rectangles
  var distance = 100; // Distance to move each rectangle

  // Check if the click target is a rectangle
  if (event.target.classList.contains('rectangle')) {
    // Move the rectangles to the left to create a gap
    for (var i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
      rectangles[i].style.left = (i * -(distance + gap)) + 'px';
    }
  } else {
    // Reset the position of all rectangles to 0
    for (var i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
      rectangles[i].style.left = '0px';
    }
  }

  // Prevent click event from bubbling up to the body
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
/* CSS to style the rectangles */

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.rectangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;       /* Set position to absolute */
  border-radius: 10px;      /* Adjust border radius for rectangle shape */
  transform: rotate(90deg); /* Rotate rectangles by 90 degrees */
  transform-origin: center; /* Set transform origin to the center */
  transition: left 0.5s;    /* Add transition for smooth movement */
  cursor: pointer;          /* Change cursor to pointer when hovering over rectangles */
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="moveRectangles(event)">
  <div class="rectangle" style="left: 0px;"></div>
  <div class="rectangle" style="left: 0px;"></div>
  <div class="rectangle" style="left: 0px;"></div>
  <div class="rectangle" style="left: 0px;"></div>
  <div class="rectangle" style="left: 0px;"></div>
  <div class="rectangle" style="left: 0px;"></div>
</div>
```

I tried like making the function such that when someone **clicks** the **blank space** other than rectangle then the animation should be reversed but im not getting hold of the function on reversing it cause it just sits without doing anything. Like if i click first on the rectangle then then normally it opens or rises up anything u want to call to the left then it should reverse that action when i click the blank space.

It should be like this :
[these are the steps of the whole animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVK79.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `else` is never hit, because you can never click inside the container currently. Add a border around the container and you will see why.

It is positioned absolutely and does not have dimensions, so it is not affected by its children. Thus its size is 0x0. You can't click on that.

So, you will have to add the closing code to the `click` of the `document`.

```js
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', openRectangles);
document.addEventListener('click', closeRectangles);

function isContainerOpen() {
  return Boolean(document.querySelector('.container.is-open'));
}

function toggleContainerState() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  container.classList.toggle('is-open')
}

function openRectangles(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  const isOpen = isContainerOpen();
  const clickedOnRectangle = event.target.classList.contains('rectangle');
  // Check if the click target is a rectangle
  if (!isOpen && clickedOnRectangle) {
    toggleContainerState();
    var rectangles = document.querySelectorAll('.rectangle');
    var gap = 5; // Gap between rectangles
    var distance = 100; // Distance to move each rectangle
    // Move the rectangles to the left to create a gap
    for (var i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
      rectangles[i].style.left = (i * -(distance + gap)) + 'px';
    }
  }
}

function closeRectangles(event) {
  const isOpen = isContainerOpen();
  // Check if the click target is a rectangle
  if (isOpen) {
    toggleContainerState();
    var rectangles = document.querySelectorAll('.rectangle');
    // Reset the position of all rectangles to 0
    for (var i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
      rectangles[i].style.left = '0px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* CSS to style the rectangles */

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.rectangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  /* Set position to absolute */
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* Adjust border radius for rectangle shape */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Rotate rectangles by 90 degrees */
  transform-origin: center;
  /* Set transform origin to the center */
  transition: left 0.5s;
  /* Add transition for smooth movement */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Change cursor to pointer when hovering over rectangles */
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML to create the rectangles -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle" style="left: 0px;"></div>
  <div class="rectangle" style="left: 0px;"></div>
  <div class="rectangle" style="left: 0px;"></div>
  <div class="rectangle" style="left: 0px;"></div>
  <div class="rectangle" style="left: 0px;"></div>
  <div class="rectangle" style="left: 0px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You for your help i really needed that. Thank You so much

Answer (score 0):

Your `if condition` is wrong. You're checking if the element contains elements with classes `.rectangle`. Instead, you can check the `left` property of a certain element at a certain index. e.g:

```
// Check if the click target is a rectangle
      if (event.target.classList.contains('rectangle') && rectangles[1].style.left === "0px") {
      // the condition above now also checks if the second rectangle's left is 0px
      // Move the rectangles to the left to create a gap
      for (var i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
        rectangles[i].style.left = (i * -(distance + gap)) + 'px';
      }
```

In this logic, we are checking if the `left` property of the second rectangle is equal to 0px, if so we animate it out, otherwise we reverse the animation.

**EDIT:** How is this different from before?
Before the if-else condition was checking if the parent element has children element with class `.rectangle`. So the else statement would only run if there were no rectangles. Now, it checks if the left property of the second element is 0px, and in this case else statement would run if it is something else than 0px.

Comment: the `contains` is run on the `classlist`. So it is only checking if the clicked element was a `.rectangle`. Not if it was containing them.

Answer (score 0):

> The primary difference in the updated code is the check for the 'hidden' class to determine the current state of visibility. While the initial if-else structure checks if the first rectangle has the 'hidden' class, the updated script uses the 'hidden' class to toggle visibility.

Here's an alternative example with a more explicit approach, using a separate variable to track the visibility state:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Move and Open Orange Rectangles</title>
    <style>
        /* CSS to style the rectangles */
        .container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .rectangle {
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: orange;
            position: absolute;
            /* Set position to absolute */
            border-radius: 10px;
            /* Adjust border radius for rectangle shape */
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            /* Rotate rectangles by 90 degrees */
            transform-origin: center;
            /* Set transform origin to the center */
            transition: left 0.5s;
            /* Add transition for smooth movement */
            cursor: pointer;
            /* Change cursor to pointer when hovering over rectangles */
        }

        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- HTML to create the rectangles -->
    <div class="container" onclick="toggleRectangles()">
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var isHidden = false;

        function toggleRectangles() {
            var rectangles = document.querySelectorAll('.rectangle');
            var gap = 5; // Gap between rectangles
            var distance = 100; // Distance to move each rectangle

            // Toggle visibility state
            isHidden = !isHidden;

            // Toggle the 'hidden' class on each rectangle
            rectangles.forEach(function (rectangle, index) {
                rectangle.style.left = isHidden ? '0px' : (index * -(distance + gap)) + 'px';
            });

            // Prevent click event from bubbling up to the body
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank You for ur answer but i wanted it ito close when i click anywhere except the boxes i.e. the blank white space but your one closes when i click in again. Nvm thank you for your interest i really appreciate your approach.

Comment: You're welcome! I understand your clarification now.